# Struts2: call method in Action class without struts tag

Tags: struts2, el

I have the following class:

```
public class HomeAction extends ActionSupport {

public String execute() {
    ...
}

public String getPippo() {
    return "pippo";
}
```

I link this action in struts.xml config file:

```
<action name="home" class="path/to/HomeAction">
   <result name="success">/jsp/home.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And in the related jsp page

```
// home.jsp

// this works
<s:property value="getPippo()"/>

// this doesn't work
${getPippo()}
```

I tried also different scope (page, session, application) but It says that It cannot find the function. I'm missing something?

Comment: Did you try ${pippo} ?

Comment: and `%{getPippo()}` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between # , % and $ signs in Struts tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007858/whats-the-difference-between-and-signs-in-struts-tags)

Comment: Use  `${pippo}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Action class in JSP using Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504365/accessing-action-class-in-jsp-using-struts2)

Comment: you should try in the request scope.

Comment: `${pippo}` would be the default access mechanism.